# freeglut window init + glew 3.0 context creation does not work

Tags: c++, opengl, glew, freeglut, openglcontext

I am trying to create a window with freeglut and then use glew to create a 3.2 context in order to use modern OpenGL functions (using c++ and a Windows pc). My Problem is that the context creation (which i tried to do both before and after the freeglut init) does not seem to work and I get an Access Violation every time i try to use a function like glCreateShader.

The code I use Looks like this (it is located right at the start of the int main(int argc, char **argv) method):

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitWindowPosition(-1, -1);
glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA || GLUT_DOUBLE || GLUT_DEPTH);

glutCreateWindow("some title");


glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
GLenum err = glewInit();

 if (GLEW_OK != err)
 {
   fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
 }
 fprintf(stdout, "Status: Using GLEW %s\n", glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION));
 if (GLEW_VERSION_3_2)
 {
    fprintf(stdout, "OpenGL 3.2 ready", glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION));
 }
...
vertexShader;
vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER); //<-- Access Violation
```

Also, the glew init code is copied 1:1 from their Website.
I hope that my mistake is not too obvious and that someone finds the time to help me.

Comment: Are you sure your graphics card supports it?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention this. Yes, I am. I got a hd 7950 with the newest driver, it should Support even 4.2

Comment: So your code prints that OpenGL 3.2 is ready etc, but the functions crash?

Comment: Tile says 3.0, body says 3.2.  Which do you actually want?  Core or compatibility?

Comment: Why aren't you using [`glutInitContext*()` and friends](http://openglbook.com/the-book/chapter-1-getting-started/)?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the FreeGLUT documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a problem there:

> ```
> glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA || GLUT_DOUBLE || GLUT_DEPTH);
> ```

Boolean OR `||` is something different than bit OR `|`. You want to **bit** OR bitmasks `|`, not boolean or them. Apart from that, in this way you will get a OpenGL-3 compatibility profile context, not a core context.

Comment: Oh, thank you. This mistake was just stupid, I don't really know why I did that...         But how can i create a core context?

Comment: @user1059863: *FreeGLUT* provides a set of extension functions `glutInitContextVersion(majorVersion, minorVersion)`, `glutInitContextFlags(flags); flags: GLUT_DEBUG, GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE`, `glutInitContextProfile(profile); profile: GLUT_CORE_PROFILE ^ GLUT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE`, which if set before calling `glutCreateWindow(…)` will influence context creation to create a context with the selected properties.